# Date convert not working with style 103

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have saved my date as a `nvarchar(50)` datatype in SQL Server. When I run this query:

```
select [Client_code], Date_of_receipt 
from [T_Receving]
```

I am getting output like this:

[image]

but I want to filter my records by particular date, so I wrote a query like this

```
select 
    convert(date, [Date_of_receipt], 103) as 'Date_of_Receipt' 
from  
    [T_Receving]  
where  
    convert(date, [Date_of_receipt], 103) between '2015-03-06' and '2018-05-06'
```

but its showing an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Why store date values as `nvarchar(50)` instead of `date`?

Comment: Since you are on 2008, I would suggest identifying and correcting your data via Select * from [T_Receving] where isdate(Date_of_receipt)=0

Comment: @DanGuzman by mistake i have done,but now i want to filter my records with date time

Comment: @JohnCappelletti,around 70 records am getting while running that query..what i want to do new with that records

Comment: @user3262364 Data Hygiene is paramount.  You have to either correct, remove, null, or filter 70+ records.  Also, this should be considered a Life Lesson to use the appropriate data types... dates should be stored as dates, not strings.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti ,,how i can correct his records ,any hint?

Comment: @user3262364 give me an example of a bogus date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170466/discussion-between-user3262364-and-john-cappelletti).

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert to datetime and then convert back to varchar

```
 declare @dtv varchar(20) = '2018-17-04'
 declare @dtvdt datetime = convert(datetime, @dtv, 103) 
 select  @dtvdt;
 select convert(varchar(20), convert(datetime, @dtv, 103), 103), @dtv
 where  convert(datetime, @dtv, 103) between '2015-03-06' and '2018-05-06'
```

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have some bad data.  Use `try_convert()`:

```
select try_convert(DATE, Date_of_receipt, 103) as Date_of_Receipt 
from T_Receving
where try_convert(DATE, Date_of_receipt, 103) between '2015-03-06' and '2018-05-06'  ;
```

In SQL Server 2008, you have to work harder to find the culprits.  You can start with:

```
select date_of_receipt
from T_Receving
where date_of_receipt not like '[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

This will find most instances of bad formats.  If it still persists, you will have to dig deeper to find bad day or month numbers.

Comment: am working on sql server 2008,try_convert function is not there

Comment: @user3262364 . . . You should tag your question appropriately.  SQL Server 2008 is pretty old now.

Comment: sorry sir,what i can do now?

Comment: i have run qeury Select * from [T_Receving] where isdate(Date_of_receipt)=0  ,,i am getting 70 records

Comment: anything i want to do with that?

Comment: @user3262364, execute update statements to change the invalid dates to valid values.

Comment: @user3262364 . . . `isdate()` may not be appropriate, because it depends on the internationalization settings to determine which grouping is the month and which is the day (and year).